# Email still dropping into SPAM after SPF etc.; why?

Tags: email, phpmailer, spam-prevention, spf, email-spam

I've automated the sending of my e-mails in PHP using PHPMailer:

```
$mail->isSMTP();

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

$mail->Host = $host; // verified with my host 
$mail->Port = 465;

$mail->Username = 'mymail@example.com'; // verified with my host 
$mail->Password = 'mypassword'; // verified with my host 

$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = true;
$mail->setFrom( 'mymail@example.com', 'This is the Header of the E-Mail' );
$mail->addAddress( 'recipientsmail@hisexample.com', '' );
$mail->isHTML( true );
$mail->Subject = 'This is the Subject of the E-Mail';
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Body = 'HTML Content of the E-Mail';
$mail->send();
$mail->SmtpClose();
```

First, many emails sned via this script dropped into the SPAM of my clients. I checked back with the host, and they helped me to add an SPF record:

- Type: TXT
- TTL: 300
- Value: "v=spf1 redirect=shared_host_mail_server"

This improved the non-spam delivery rate a lot, but especially for gmail, significant portion still drops into spam. An example of the source of an email that dropped into the email spam is:

```
Delivered-To: my.secret@gmail.com
Received: by 2002:a17:906:f12:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id secret;
        Mon, 21 Mar 2022 06:58:32 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: ABdhPJz6F29tChwOYHMaPAlJC0D9QTnj/JMhktHDZEuWjHBWU7x/ZdnkZS7MccoMwSxrMjrZec73
X-Received: by 2002:a5d:4ad2:0:b0:203:d56d:9c82 with SMTP id secret;
        Mon, 21 Mar 2022 06:58:30 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1647871110; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=K3FgBLtaiFZEsUAPiR2dBpquBEVEKZ2A82PhG+nCN7I7NRTxE8KDueotg3pndOeoQQ
         IaCxIO8uYvkka1BmdSz8RuL0H/+OuXh+UMTpuy5tnhteTy3IR5Ub8vfl2eCl5AsCUj1R
         ZLkysapUMphblFlZnSz4JObVz0jgN8P4uAE39ObN1YVpLZ9bT//BXuVjyYbKuHyhDUoP
         AnZ+cjey7I4dyuvaaUWyrIMC7xEnLratGSN4mtIBWhEuWrMokXZtnbVZMHtNh+W7d5d1
         HGmWzWdnWftGZJFI8e2fnNSRosRE0pwzblCNAkGd+PmJHOEDlq5pmaLla1I9yZpxZa3z
         dx4w==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=content-transfer-encoding:mime-version:message-id:subject:from:to
         :date;
        bh=NCbhFSalLdDA2HAK57ps0Gy6VG+hTVJz6G8PW0XPkpo=;
        b=TuIDSDjGMJOISTWTkb8iaOA1qJ3QYFLU6adhuG2kbyzpICBc0EC5MNvkGDWcEH9znp
         UjYJ0Uug/79c6ZSzLaXuv3THIwuO7MJTuM5r7YXTbFvGnwNlO/Qc1xO/bo63rIN1ZS8y
         aKRtpzjO0hMqjxlbltnZPcNice0DqZZcX0BlaU8kkgKFGw96vpBj9A0ZZbAyvmK2Lyws
         oGYdKUmcOhosxXIxM8AAu1JVtM0bI2EncDo5UvwBIXVitvgcmORTfS1u3RBsKakk9tXI
         bBCer6hxpjjn+hRxMOsdjqFdLa0EIIxnuW/z05Yh4CYSPBi1RZM0q/hWCMPvjDqBRFY5
         8vVQ==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of secret.sender@example.com designates 2a00:d70:0:e::313 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=secret.sender@example.com
Return-Path: <secret.sender@example.com>
Received: from host_out_mail_server (host_out_mail_server. [2a00:d70:0:e::313])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id secret
        for <my.secret@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_3 cipher=TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 bits=256/256);
        Mon, 21 Mar 2022 06:58:30 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of secret.sender@example.com designates secret_ip as permitted sender) client-ip=secret_ip;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of secret.sender@example.com designates secret.sender@example.com as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=secret.sender@example.com
Received: from [10.0.2.46] (helo=host_mail_server) by host_out_mail_server with esmtps
  (TLS1.3) tls TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (Exim 4.94.2 (FreeBSD)) (envelope-from <secret.sender@example.com>) id 1nWIYH-0000QW-8D for my.secret@gmail.com; Mon, 21 Mar 2022 14:58:29 +0100
Received: from other_host_server ([2a00:d70:0:b::2:10] helo=example.com) by host_mail_server with esmtpa (Exim 4.95 (FreeBSD)) (envelope-from <secret.sender@example.com>) id 1nWIYG-00010j-7w for my.secret@gmail.com; Mon, 21 Mar 2022 14:58:29 +0100
X-Authenticated-Sender-Id: secret.sender@example.com
Date: Mon, 21 Mar 2022 13:58:28 +0000
To: my.secret@gmail.com
From: Werbe - Anfrage <secret.sender@example.com>
Subject: Bekanntmachung
Message-ID: <secret@example.com>
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 6.5.0 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="b1_ciluFWHutVghcyNH2SHrnSBIhFM0AuGhsYu8JefeYks"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

--b1_ciluFWHutVghcyNH2SHrnSBIhFM0AuGhsYu8JefeYks
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=3D"de" xmlns=3D"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:o=3D"urn:sch=
emas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<head>
  <meta charset=3D"UTF-8">
  <meta name=3D"viewport" content=3D"width=3Ddevice-width,initial-scale=3D1=
">
  <meta name=3D"x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">
  <title></title>
  <!--[if mso]>
  <style type=3D"text/css">
        table {border-collapse:collapse;border:0;border-spacing:0;margin:0;=
}
        div, td {padding:0;}
        div {margin:0 !important;}
    </style>
    <noscript>
        <xml>
            <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
                <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
            </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
        </xml>
    </noscript>
    <![endif]-->
  <style type=3D"text/css">
    /* CLIENT-SPECIFIC STYLES */
    body,
    table,
    td,
    a {
      -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    }

    table,
    td {
      mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
      mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
    }

    img {
      -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
    }

    /* RESET STYLES */
    img {
      border: 0;
      height: auto;
      line-height: 100%;
      outline: none;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    table {
      border-collapse: collapse !important;
    }

    body {
      height: 100% !important;
      margin: 0 !important;
      padding: 0 !important;
      width: 100% !important;
    }

    /* iOS BLUE LINKS */
    a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
      color: inherit !important;
      text-decoration: none !important;
      font-size: inherit !important;
      font-family: inherit !important;
      font-weight: inherit !important;
      line-height: inherit !important;
    }

    /* MOBILE STYLES */
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .img-max {
        width: 100% !important;
        max-width: 100% !important;
        height: auto !important;
      }

      .max-width {
        max-width: 100% !important;
      }

      .mobile-wrapper {
        width: 85% !important;
        max-width: 85% !important;
      }

      .mobile-padding {
        padding-left: 5% !important;
        padding-right: 5% !important;
      }
    }

    /* ANDROID CENTER FIX */
    div[style*=3D"margin: 16px 0;"] {
      margin: 0 !important;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body style=3D"margin: 0 !important; padding: 0; !important; word-spacing: =
normal; background-color: #ffffff;" bgcolor=3D"#ffffff">

<div style=3D"display: none; font-size: 1px; color: #fefefe; line-height: 1=
px; font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; max-height: 0px; =
max-width: 0px; opacity: 0; overflow: hidden;">
    This is the text of the preheader
</div>

<table role=3D"presentation" border=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"=
0" width=3D"100%" bgcolor=3D"#d3d3d3" style=3D"background: #d3d3d3;">
    <tr>
        <td align=3D"center" valign=3D"top" width=3D"100%" style=3D"padding=
: 0;">

            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            <table role=3D"presentation" align=3D"center" border=3D"0" cell=
spacing=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0" width=3D"600">
            <tr>
            <td align=3D"center" valign=3D"top" width=3D"600">
            <![endif]-->

            <table role=3D"presentation" align=3D"center" border=3D"0" cell=
padding=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" width=3D"100%" style=3D"max-width:600px;">
                <tr>
    <td align=3D"center" valign=3D"top" style=3D"padding: 0; border-left: 1=
px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #000000; border-bottom: 1px solid=
 #000000;">
        <img src=3D"https://example.com/mail_visual.png" wi=
dth=3D"600" border=3D"0" alt=3D"" style=3D"display: block; width: 100%; hei=
ght:auto;" class=3D"img-max"/>
    </td>
</tr>

                <tr>
    <td align=3D"left" valign=3D"top" bgcolor=3D"#ffffff" style=3D"backgrou=
nd: #ffffff; padding: 15px 30px 30px 30px; font-family: Open Sans, Helvetic=
a, Arial, sans-serif; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px sol=
id #000000;">
        <h4 style=3D"font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; =
font-size: 17px; line-height: 23px; color: #000000;">Salutation</h4>
        <p style=3D"color: #000000; font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Aria=
l, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 22px; margin: 0;">Sample Context</p>
    </td>
</tr>

                <tr>
    <td align=3D"center" valign=3D"top" bgcolor=3D"#13aff0" style=3D"backgr=
ound: #13aff0; padding: 10px 30px; font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial=
, sans-serif; border-left: 1px solid #000000; border-right: 1px solid #0000=
00; border-top: 1px solid #000000;">

      <h5 style=3D"font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; fo=
nt-size: 16px; line-height: 24px; color: #ffffff; margin:0 0 5px 0;">Domai=
n</h5>
      <img src=3D"https://example.com/icons/first.png" width=3D"107" he=
ight=3D"40" border=3D"0" alt=3D"first" style=3D"display: bl=
ock; border: 0px; color: #999999; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 18px;=
" />
      <p style=3D"margin:7px 0 15px 0;"><a href=3D"mailto:secret.sender=
@example.com" target=3D"_blank" style=3D"text-decoration: none; color: #fff=
fff; font-family: Open Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px;=
 line-height: 16px;">secret.sender@example.com</a></p>
      <p style=3D"margin:0 0 14px 0;"><a href=3D"https://example.com" targe=
t=3D"_blank" style=3D"text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; font-family: O=
pen Sans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 16px;=
">www.example.com</a></p>

      <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
      <table role=3D"presentation" align=3D"center" border=3D"0" cellspacin=
g=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0" width=3D"157">
      <tr>
      <td align=3D"center" valign=3D"top" width=3D"157">
      <![endif]-->

      <table role=3D"presentation" align=3D"center" border=3D"0" cellpaddin=
g=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" width=3D"100%" style=3D"max-width:157px;">
        <tr>
          <td style=3D"padding:0;">
            <a href=3D"https://www.instagram.com/companylink/" target=3D"_blank=
" style=3D"text-decoration: none;"><img src=3D"https://example.com/icons/In=
stagram.png" alt=3D"Link for Instagram Channel" width=3D"30" height=
=3D"30" style=3D"height:auto;display:block;border:0;" /></a>
          </td>
          <td style=3D"padding:0 0 0 15px;">
            <a href=3D"https://www.linkedin.com/company/name" target=3D"=
_blank" style=3D"text-decoration: none;"><img src=3D"https://example.com/ic=
ons/LinkedIn.png" alt=3D"Link for LinkedIn Channel" width=3D"30" he=
ight=3D"30" style=3D"height:auto;display:block;border:0;" /></a>
          </td>
          <td style=3D"padding:0 0 0 15px;">
            <a href=3D"https://twitter.com/companyname" target=3D"_blank" style=
=3D"text-decoration: none;"><img src=3D"https://example.com/icons/Twitter.p=
ng" alt=3D"Link for Twitter Channel" width=3D"30" height=3D"30" sty=
le=3D"height:auto;display:block;border:0;" /></a>
          </td>
          <td style=3D"padding:0 0 0 7px;">
            <a href=3D"https://www.facebook.com/compnyname" ta=
rget=3D"_blank" style=3D"text-decoration: none;"><img src=3D"https://domai=
n.com/icons/Facebook.png" alt=3D"Link for Facebook Channel" width=
=3D"30" height=3D"30" style=3D"height:auto;display:block;border:0;" /></a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
      </td>
      </tr>
      </table>
      <![endif]-->

    </td>
</tr>

            </table>

            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <![endif]-->

        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

--b1_ciluFWHutVghcyNH2SHrnSBIhFM0AuGhsYu8JefeYks
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=QR_DE.pdf
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=QR_DE.pdf


--b1_ciluFWHutVghcyNH2SHrnSBIhFM0AuGhsYu8JefeYks--
```

I don't see the problem in this e-mail source extract / the reason why it drops into spam; does anyone of you?

I then checked back with the host about the particular gmail problem, and they recommended me to change my spf record to:

`"v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com redirect=shared_host_mail_server"`

But I feel that this is wrong / is only necessary if you want to send emails from your domain across gmails server's, or am I wrong?

Anyway, any suggestions on how I can improve the result? I don't use DKIM / DMARC so far, because my host does not support DKIM signing. Is it a good idea to try to implement DKIM via PHPMailer in this case / is it even possible to do so if the host server does not support DKIM natively?

Thanks in advance for any help!

P.S.: I did [this test](https://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html) and the result was:

[image]

This goes for both mentioned versions of the SPF. However if I check in other tools as mail-tester or email on acid, the SPF is valid. Just FYI

Comment: Generally `include` is what you want rather than `redirect` – your provider (if competent!) should maintain a record listing their IP ranges that you can use for that. Unfortunately no matter what you do to sign and authenticate, gmail will probably put it in spam anyway because their filtering is very poor, and they provide no user feedback mechanisms to influence its future decisions, such as using "not spam" reports, or the presence of sender addresses in your address book. Their postmaster tools are also utterly useless and provide meaningless and inconsistent data. YMMV, a lot!

Comment: It is most efficient to get your mail server to do DKIM signing for you. PHPMailer's DKIM signing has issues (I know, I wrote it!), but many find it works for them, so you could give it a try.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedbacks! Before giving it a try, you can confirm that 1) PHPMailer's DKIM signing works even if the provider's outgoing mail server does not support DKIM, and 2) that it is not tied to any risk (for example worsening the reputation I my mail server(s) currently have) ..? Sorry to ask like this, I just want to make sure that I don't make things worse, as gmail seems to be the only problem for the moment. :) And thanks a lot for your work for PHPMailer, it's awesome!

Comment: Thanks! Yes, PHPMailer's DKIM signing is independent of your mail server – you may not be aware that it's entirely valid to have more than one DKIM signature in a message, and it's quite common in practice. There is no fallout if it doesn't work – so long as you don't have a DMARC record with a long TTL, you can turn it on and off at will as you experiment, and a receiving server will not penalise you for doing so. You don't have to go all-in either – as it's just in your scripts, you can use it to send tests to a testing account only until you get it working.