# Send DKIM - signed emails through third-party email service provider API?

Tags: email, phpmailer, spam-prevention, spf, dkim

This question is a follow-up question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71781216/email-still-dropping-into-spam-after-spf-etc-why?noredirect=1#comment126861645_71781216).

The problem is that my current E-Mail provider does not natively support DKIM-signing, but I need that DKIM feature to make certain API integrations regarding my emails (like sending emails from my payment service provider through my own domain).

The solution I'm starting to see, as long as my host does not DKIM-sign their outgoing emails, is to watch out for an email providing service that allows you to send emails in the name of your own domain including the DKIM-signature feature. Does such a service exist, via API call? I've no experience whatsoever in this area, and would be happy to know if such a setup potentially has a bad influence on delivery rates / other problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the mail server signs using your domain and not theirs, and you post the matching public key in your DNS, it will all work fine. You do need to find a provider that lets you do that though, which they may do via CNAME records. Such services will often allow you to configure what the mail server does with your messages using additional params in an HTTP API, or via custom headers over SMTP, e.g. it might allow you to set a header like:

```
Sign-with-selector: myselector
```

Recommendations for services are off-limits for SO though.

Comment: pleasure to learn from your answers, as usual!

Comment: "If the mail server signs using your domain and not theirs, and you post the matching public key in your DNS, it will all work fine." This is exactly how I was able to set this up, and my mails now show up as DKIM-signed and spam tester scores also improved from 7.5/10 to 9.5/10. And, as you said correctly, all I had to do is include an additional DNS CNAME record + the inclusion of the mail server of the API provider within the SPF - record of my DNS zone; all working now. Result: Mails are sent from my mail addresses through their servers (hence the need for their SPF, I guess), DKIM-signed.

Comment: @DevelJoe great stuff!

Comment: I however had to replace PHPMailer with the according API PHP package; I'm now completely sending my e-mails through their API, and no longer through SMTP using PHPMailer.